# How to choose a single most common label from multiple labels? using python

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have acceleration (only x-Axis) signal and for each sample, i have a label (encoded as one hot code).

-This is how my **acceleration** signal looks like:

```
0     0.294132
1    -0.499688
2    -2.178345
3    -2.797763
4    -2.167961
5    -1.734857
6    -1.463939
7    -0.945008
8     0.182038
9     0.948368
10    1.675603

    ...   
95    0.793209
96   -0.023213
97    0.284969
98   -0.170126
99   -2.005471
Name: X-Axis, Length: 100, dtype: float64
```

-This is how each **label** looks like:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=int8)
```

How can I select one label for every 100 Samples? In other words how can i squeeze this label array from (100,6) to (1,6) such that most occouring label (with highest probability is selected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that `a` is the array you posted above, you can just sum over the array `a` on the dimension 0, found the maximum value of the resulting sum and extracting its position:

```
import tensorflow as tf

labels = tf.constant(a, dtype=tf.int32)

# count number of labels for every position
count = tf.reduce_sum(labels, axis=[0])
# count has shape (6)

# get the label with the higher count value
top_label = tf.argmax(count)

# One hot encode the label to get the same representation
one_hot_top_label = tf.one_hot(top_label, count.shape[0], dtype=tf.int32)


sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print(sess.run([count, top_label, one_hot_top_label]))
```

And you get:

```
[array([ 0,  1,  1,  0,  0, 98], dtype=int32), 
5,
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int32)]
```